# Decode text which is coded with the Huffman algorithm

Tags: algorithm, huffman-code

Is there any chance to decode a big text which is coded with the Huffman algorithm? (I dont have the code tree, and im sure the original text is in english language)

Comment: Can you give us some context here? Why are you trying to do this? Is this practical or just theoretical? Is this homework?

Comment: Using frequency analysis of letters in "normal" english text, you may be able to deduce a code tree. Not a simple task though.

Comment: Do you know whether the Huffman code represents single letters or entire words?

Comment: @ErnestV there is a reason LMGTFY links are forbidden here. The reason is not so that you would have to use a minifer.

Comment: Thanks @JanDvorak, didn't know that. Seems I need to read the bylines carefully ;-)

Comment: @Craigy it is just theoretical. it just came to my mind

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz in this case i just thought letter representation

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the tree, then you would have to construct it. It is essentially the part of Huffman encoding algorithm, right before you need to construct the string.

Now, if you don't know the frequency of the characters in your text, that might be a problem, because characters might be represented by different number of digits. This is an example of Huffman encoding with unequal letter cost.

If that is not the case and each letter has an equal cost, then you would be able to deduce a tree, but it would be quite difficult because you would need to try out different assignment of letter for the code, before you end up with a legitimate map.

Once you have the tree, decoding shouldn't be much of a problem ( in theory, at least). 
Here are couple of resources that talk about encoding/decoding with Huffman alg:
    [Wiki-page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding#Basic_technique) ,
    [2](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~kirk/cs1501/animations/Huffman.html),
    [applet](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/365/li/squeeze/Huffman.html)

Comment: to me, the real problem is to determine which are the different letters

Comment: @HeapOwerflow, Once again, if you know that every letter will have same number of bits that encode it, then you can deduce letters. Wiki page talks about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding#Decompression

But how exactly to do it, I am not sure.  I hope my answers helped you, in some way.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you cannot decode the text easily, the reason being that *any* valid Huffman tree can be used to decode *any* Huffman code (or any random bitstream, for what it's worth). Therefore, you have no way of recreating the original tree used to generate the code just from the code itself.

You could try to generate the code dynamically by matching the output to a dictionary and changing the code upon a mismatch, then restarting the decoding. I have no idea how practical such a brute-force approach would be, though.